# How to get all tables that start with this string "mytable_" in QuestDB web ui?

Tags: sql, questdb

How can you run a SELECT query that selects all table names that start with the string "mytable_" in QuestDB web ui?

Answer (score 0):

The QuestDB web UI can execute arbitrary SQL queries. QuestDB has a built-in table function `tables()` which returns all tables. To get all tables with a name starting with `mytable_` you simply execute this SQL:

```sql
SELECT table_name FROM tables()
WHERE table_name LIKE 'mytable_%'
```